# Free education Chrome App not appearing in Web Store

Tags: google-chrome-app

I created a free education Chrome App and uploaded it via the Chrome Developer Dashboard. The App doesn't appear when I search for it with the Web Store search feature. Is there something missing in the manifest file or the descriptive material? There is no website associated with this App.
Thanks.

Edit: Thanks for the answer.  Patience is the key with the Google Chrome Store.

Comment: Probably the search index is not rebuilt that often. Give it a day.

Comment: Xan, yes you're correct.  It's there now.  Many thanks. Glen

Comment: I added this as an answer - I would appreciate if you mark it as accepted (it will also give you a little reputation).

Answer (score 0):

The search index of Web Store is (probably) not updated immediately after publishing an extension/app.

Retrying the search a couple of hours after publication is complete will show it like normal.

Also, make sure your extension is actually published, and not stuck in automated or manual review. The former takes up to an hour, the latter can take days. Check your [Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard) for the status of your item.